# Callback from AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback

This is my AsyncTask:

```
public class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<Context, String, JSONObject> {
    private Context context = null;
    private OnRegisterTaskCompleted onRegisterTaskCompleted = null;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private String firstname = null;
    private String lastname = null;
    private String email = null;
    private String password = null;

    public RegisterTask(Context context, OnRegisterTaskCompleted onRegisterTaskCompleted, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password) {
        this.context = context;
        this.onRegisterTaskCompleted = onRegisterTaskCompleted;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        this.progressDialog = DialogManager.getProgressDialog(this.context, this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.title_progress), this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_registration_progress));
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Context... context) {
        ConnectionEstablisher connectionEstablisher = new ConnectionEstablisher(this.context);
        JSONFunctions jsonFunctions = new JSONFunctions(connectionEstablisher);
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            json = jsonFunctions.registerUser(this.firstname, this.lastname, this.email, this.password);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_PROTOCOL_EXCEPTION, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_IO_EXCEPTION, null);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_JSON_EXCEPTION, null);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_NO_SUCH_ALGO_EXCEPTION, null);
        }

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        if(this.progressDialog != null && this.progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        try {
            if (json.getString(Globals.JSON_KEY_CODE) != null) {
                if(json.getString(Globals.JSON_KEY_CODE).equals(Globals.JSON_STATUS_REGISTRATION_COMPLETED)) {
                    JSONObject jsonUser = json.getJSONObject(Globals.JSON_KEY_USER);

                    this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_OK, jsonUser);
                } else if (json.getString(Globals.JSON_KEY_CODE).equals(Globals.JSON_STATUS_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS)) {
                    this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS, null);
                } else if (json.getString(Globals.JSON_KEY_CODE).equals(Globals.JSON_STATUS_DB_CONNECTION_FAILED)) {
                    this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_DB_CONNECTION_FAILED, null);
                } else {
                    this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_CONNECTION_FAILED, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            this.onRegisterTaskCompleted.onRegisterTaskCompleted(Globals.STATUS_JSON_EXCEPTION, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener, OnRegisterTaskCompleted {
    private EditText textEditFirstName = null;
    private EditText textEditLastName = null;
    private EditText textEditEmail = null;
    private CheckBox checkBoxShowPassword = null;
    private EditText textEditPassword = null;
    private Button buttonRegister = null;
    private Button buttonCancel = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        this.textEditFirstName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.register_textedit_firstname);
        this.textEditLastName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.register_textedit_lastname);
        this.textEditEmail = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.register_textedit_email);
        this.checkBoxShowPassword = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.register_checkbox_password);
        this.checkBoxShowPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        this.textEditPassword = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.register_textedit_password);
        this.buttonRegister = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.register_button_register);
        this.buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.buttonCancel = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.register_button_cancel);
        this.buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(Globals.KEY_FIRSTNAME, this.textEditFirstName.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(Globals.KEY_LASTNAME, this.textEditLastName.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(Globals.KEY_EMAIL, this.textEditEmail.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(Globals.KEY_PASSWORD, this.textEditPassword.getText().toString());
        outState.putBoolean(Globals.KEY_SHOW_PASSWORD, this.checkBoxShowPassword.isChecked());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.register_button_register : {
                this.performRegister();
            } break;
            case R.id.register_button_cancel : {
                this.performCancel();
            } break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (!isChecked) {
            this.textEditPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        } else {
            this.textEditPassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegisterTaskCompleted(int status, JSONObject jsonUser) {
        switch(status) {
            case Globals.STATUS_OK : {
                Toast.makeText(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_registration_completed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                this.finish();
            } break;
            case Globals.STATUS_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS : {
                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_email_already_exists));
            } break;
            case Globals.STATUS_DB_CONNECTION_FAILED : {
                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_db_connection_failed));
            } break;
            case Globals.STATUS_CONNECTION_FAILED : {
                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_connection_failed));
            } break;
            case Globals.STATUS_PROTOCOL_EXCEPTION : {
                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_protocol_exception));
            } break;
            case Globals.STATUS_IO_EXCEPTION : {
                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_io_exception));
            } break;
            case Globals.STATUS_JSON_EXCEPTION : {
                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_json_exception));
            } break;
            case Globals.STATUS_NO_SUCH_ALGO_EXCEPTION : {
                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_algorithm_exception));
            } break;
        }

        this.buttonRegister.setEnabled(true);
        this.buttonCancel.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void restoreState(Bundle inState) {
        if(inState != null) {
            this.textEditFirstName.setText(inState.getString(Globals.KEY_FIRSTNAME));
            this.textEditLastName.setText(inState.getString(Globals.KEY_LASTNAME));
            this.textEditEmail.setText(inState.getString(Globals.KEY_EMAIL));
            this.textEditPassword.setText(inState.getString(Globals.KEY_PASSWORD));
            this.checkBoxShowPassword.setChecked(inState.getBoolean(Globals.KEY_SHOW_PASSWORD));
        }
    }

    private void performRegister() {
        int result = this.checkFormFields();

        if(result == Globals.STATUS_OK) {
            String firstname = this.textEditFirstName.getText().toString();
            String lastname = this.textEditLastName.getText().toString();
            String email = this.textEditEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = this.textEditPassword.getText().toString();

            this.buttonRegister.setEnabled(false);
            this.buttonCancel.setEnabled(false);

            RegisterTask registerTask = new RegisterTask(this, this, firstname, lastname, email, password);
            registerTask.execute(this);
        } else if(result == Globals.INPUT_MISSING_FN) {
            DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_missing_fn));
        } else if(result == Globals.INPUT_MISSING_LN) {
            DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_missing_ln));
        } else if(result == Globals.INPUT_MISSING_EMAIL) {
            DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_missing_email));
        } else if(result == Globals.INPUT_INVALID_EMAIL) {
            DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_invalid_email));
        } else if(result == Globals.INPUT_MISSING_PW) {
            DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_missing_pw));
        } else if(result == Globals.INPUT_INVALID_PASSWORD) {
            DialogManager.showAlertDialog(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error), this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_invalid_pw));
        }
    }

    private void performCancel() {
         this.finish();
    }

    private int checkFormFields() {
        if(this.textEditFirstName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return Globals.INPUT_MISSING_FN;
        } else if(this.textEditLastName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return Globals.INPUT_MISSING_LN;
        } else if(this.textEditEmail.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return Globals.INPUT_MISSING_EMAIL;
        } else if(!Validation.validateEmail(this.textEditEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
            return Globals.INPUT_INVALID_EMAIL;
        } else if(this.textEditPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            return Globals.INPUT_MISSING_PW;
        } else if(!Validation.validatePassword(this.textEditPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
            return Globals.INPUT_INVALID_PASSWORD;
        } else {
            return Globals.STATUS_OK;
        }
    }
}
```

When i catch an exception in the `doInBackground` method and i call my callback 
method i get this error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

It is ONLY when i call it from `doInBackground` so i guess it happens because
of the dialog and toast messages on the background thread. I need to call them
on the UI thread an i need a pretty solution for this.

Comment: this link does not tell me anything i dont know yet and it is not related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it from a worker thread. Either you can call Looper.prepare() from handler or use the runOnUiThread method like this:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // your code goes here...for exception handling..
    }
});
```

Comment: oh but then i have to give the activity as a parameter to my AsyncTask. Isnt it kind of "ugly-code"?

Comment: yeah...i think you are getting error on .. Toast.makeText()... try using getApplicationContext() instead of "this" in the makeText method.

Comment: no i get the error from DialogManager.showAlertDialog and for that i have to give 'this' as parameter. for 'this.getApplicationContext()' i get an error when calling a dialog. The Toast does not cause the error because the toast is never called from the doInBackground(). doInBackground only calls the callback method when an error appears. If everything is alright the callback method is called in postExecute.

Comment: so is there something more pretty? can i also call this.runOnUiThread in my callback method?

Comment: please post the full code including onPostExecute... method..IF the exception in postExecute then it should not show error...

Comment: No need to pass activity as parameter. Just get it from your context, Activity activity = (Activity)this.context; 

Let's know, if it works.

Comment: Nope. does not work. unfortunately the callback method is never called when i use the runOnUiThread

Comment: All callback methods should be triggered from onPostExecute not doInBackground, I think you should reconsider your logic. Similarly Toast or Dialog, all should be called in onPostExecute, that is what "onPostExecute" for